# Extract parts of first row in CSV and create columns

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

Following situation:

- I have an .csv file as input
- The .csv is an export from an tool
- The export generates an "Metadata" entry in row1, column1
- Row headers of the data are in row2
- data starts from row 3

The "Metadata" has the following schema:

*String1 - String2 - INT1/INT2/INT3 / String3 - String4 - String5 (String6) String7*

Sample:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Metadata" |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header5 | Header6 | Header7 | Header8 | Header9 | Header10 | Header11 | Header12 |
| "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" |
| "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" |

My Goals:

Create an Data Flow:

- Extract the "Metadata", split it up by the Delimiters "/", " - ", "(" and ")" and make the each parts usable in derived columns and sink filename
- Create three new columns, with column headers based on "String3", "String6" and "String7"
- Create dynamic sink filename based on "Metadata": *"String6"."String7"_"String3".csv*

So at the end there is an table with column headers from row 2, data beginning from row 3, three new columns based on parts of "Metadata" and an dynamic filename based on parts from "Metadata":

*String6.String7_String3.csv*:

| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 | Header4 | Header5 | Header6 | Header7 | Header8 | Header9 | Header10 | Header11 | Header12 | "AdditionalColumn1" | "AdditionalColumn2" | "AdditionalColumn3" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "String3" | "String6" | "String7" |
| "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "Data" | "String3" | "String6" | "String7" |

Comment: **Schemas** and **Columns** of the source data have a one-to-one correspondence? There are 12 columns and 10 schemas.

Comment: I have already an target database with the corresponding schema prepared and manually filled with data for testing. This part is done. Now I want to automate it through the Azure Data Factory and struggling with the source .csv. I don't want to edit the .csv manually before upload it to the ADF. It must be possible to automate it.

Comment: Oh and totally forgotten: I only need the mentioned parts from the "Metadata" entry in "A1" to use them as new column with corresponding names and also for the dynamic filename in output

Comment: Hi @DerKamiKatze , I have figured it out and modified on this basis, but sorry I can't reply in time, I will reply you next Monday.

Comment: Hi @DerKamiKatze I've figure it out. The test I created works well. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Joseph Xu
That is very impressive and I belive it will work.
I've tried to rebuild your model in my project but fail at the "DerivedColumn1" activity: The Output-Column is always "NULL" - no matter how I try to split.
Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: What is your Select1  preview looks like? "DerivedColumn1" activity is based on "Select1 " activity.  [This is mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5wz.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update**:
I've created a test. It can also solve the problem.
This is my data source:
[image]

My debug result of my test is as follows, it will generate one csv file:
[image]

1. The data source is to the csv file, please don't select **First row as header**.
   [image]

The **First row as header** is set false:
[image]

2. Then at the SurrogateKey1 activity, I set the values as follows:
   [image]

It will add a **row_no** column, in the form of a number incremented by 1:
[image]

3. Then I use ConditionalSplit1 activity to split the source data to 3 types data flow:
   `metadata`, `headers`, `data`.
   [image]
4. At the Select1 activity, I only select `_col0_` and name as `column0`.
   [image]
   The data preview is like this:
   [image]
5. Then I use DerivedColumn1 activity to create 3 new columns:

```
ADDITIONALCOLUMN1 => split(split({_col0_},'-')[3],'/')[4]
ADDITIONALCOLUMN2 => split(split(split({_col0_},'-')[5],'(')[2],')')[1]
ADDITIONALCOLUMN3 => split(split(split({_col0_},'-')[5],'(')[2],')')[2]
```

[image]
The data preview is like this:
[image]

6. At the Select2 activity, I only selected the 3 new columns.
   [image]
   The 3 new columns data preview is like this:
   [image]
7. At DerivedColumn2 activity, I created the FileName column:
   `concat(ADDITIONALCOLUMN2,'.',ADDITIONALCOLUMN3,'_',ADDITIONALCOLUMN1,'.csv')`
   [image]
   The data preview is like this:
   [image]
8. At Join2 activity, I use Cutomer(cross) and the Right stream is DerivedColumn1, so we can add the data we generated at DerivedColumn2 activity at the tail.
   [image]
   The data preview is like this:
   [image]
9. At DerivedColumn3 activity, I created 3 columns manually (since the Union activity will be done next, the number of columns must be the same). The FileName column expression is
   `concat(ADDITIONALCOLUMN2,'.',ADDITIONALCOLUMN3,'_',ADDITIONALCOLUMN1,'.csv')`
   [image]
   The data preview is like this:
   [image]
10. At Select6 activity, we can select the columns we need.
    The setting is as follows:
    [image]
    The data preview is like this:
    [image]
11. Then we jump to Join1 activity, the setting is as follows:
    [image]
    The data preview is like this, we can see **Custom (cross)** will add the data we generated at DerivedColumn2 activity at the tail:
    [image]
12. At Select4 activity, I selected all the columns:
    [image]
    The data preview is like this:
    [image]

13.Then we jump to Union1 activity:
[image]
The data preview is like this:
[image]

14. At Select5 activity(This step can be omitted, skip to sink1 activity directly), I selected all the columns. **We can skip this step.**
    [image]
15. At sink1 activity. The setting is as follows, it will generate a csv file with this name:
    [image]
    The data preview is like this:
    [image]

That's all.